# React prevent change state in child component when parent component update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 component, one parent, another is child component

in my parent component I'm using react-table and inside using some component where defined react-table like

```
Filter: props => <FilterInnerComponent {...props} />,
```

problem is in my child component I'm changing some state to true or false on click to some button. And when my data changes in my parent component. My child component too re-rendering and child component state back to default.

How to prevent this and keep the state of child component on last changes when parent component state change.

i research and see some resolution about :

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
}
```

but I don't know how using it. I tried this but not helped.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
   return this.state.openTextBox != nextState.openTextBox
}
```

here is where i'm using my onClick function where i change my openTextBox value on my child component

```
changeFilterType(event) {
    if(filterType !== "All"){
        this.state.openTextBox = true
      }
      else{
        this.state.openTextBox = false
      }
 }
```

Comment: Can you post some sample code ?

Comment: When parent component update's then it will change props recieved by child component. You should compare `this.props.openTextBox != nextProps.openTextBox`

Comment: Yeah, But the state will set to default only if the child remounts

Comment: to save child component state you have to move it away from state, either you can save it in parent props and directly update and read value from there or you can put in redux (if you have that).
HINT : context api

Comment: Can you show us your constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you are comparing `this.state` & `nextState`, rather than your `this.props` & `nextProps`. Your child's state shouldn't be changed by your parent, its props should.

You can either use react's `PureComponent` or `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)`.

The differences are that `PureComponent` performs a **shallow** comparison of props and state. Whereas, `shouldComponentUpdate` gives you more control over comparing **deep** props structures.

You can declare your parent component as PureComponent. If it didn't help, try using shouldComponentUpdate like so:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
   return this.props.openTextBox != nextProps.openTextBox
}
```

Comment: This time my value of openTextBox not changing in onclick function where i make it true or false

Comment: You don't have a state in your constructor. You should use a state if you want to preserve your results.

Answer (score 0):

As I can make out from your piece of code, you are using shouldComponentUpdate in the parent component.

Rather than I would say, use that in the child component. Assuming that you are only changing the boolean state value in the parent component and other data remains as it is in the logic. You can then use the object comparison method to compare between 2 props instances in the component as follows -

```
return this.state.openTextBox != nextState.openTextBox
```

If the openTextBox is just a primitve value, you can also use the Pure Component of react.

And further in onclick function you need to use something like this -

```
changeFilterType(event) {
 if(filterType !== "All"){
    this.setState({openTextBox: true});
  }
  else{
    this.setState({openTextBox: false});
  }
}
```

Comment: This time my value of openTextBox not changing in onclick function where i make it true or false

Comment: Are you using openTextBox value in the child component? Can you provide that sample of line where you are changing on click?

Comment: Yes i'm using it in my child component. I edited my question with sample

Comment: Oh okay. I thought that openTextBox is coming as a prop from the parent component. In that case, you need to check with state only in should component update. I am changing my answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you but not worked again. My state is defined like : state={
        openTextBox: false
    }

Comment: Okay. Another thing is that you are assigning the value directly to the state variable. Instead you should use setState which React provides. setState is the way in which you can allow re rendering in react rather than directly assigning. See my edited comment

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible to save the changed state in the child component and use that to override a prop from the parent component, consider to let the button trigger an event handler that changes the state on a higher level so that the new value comes back in the child component simply as a new prop value.